# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop the chrome extension where when user selects the text, that selected text will be grabbed and then send to the background script for processing the api call. Right now, the text is grabbed but i have consoled in the following line

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log('req', request.message)
```

but this is not consoled perhaps due to this block is not even called.

Here is the code

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "DEMO",
  "description": "This extension allow the user to select the text and redirect to the google to search that text",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "Logo.png",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
    "default_title": "click me"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "options_page": "html/popup.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js", "js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : [
            "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js" : [
            "js/content.js"
        ]
    }
],
  "commands": {
          "toggle-feature-foo": {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
              "mac": "Command+Shift+H"
            },
            "description": "Toggle feature foo"
          }
        }
}
```

**content.js**

```
function init(event) {
  var topic = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    topic = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection) {
      topic = document.selection.createRange().topic;
  } else {
    return topic;
  }
  if((event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 65) && topic.length) {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({'message': 'setTopic', 'data': topic}, function(response){
      console.log('response', response);
    })
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',init);
```

**background.js**

```
var selectedTopic = null;

  chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log('req', request.message) // not listened 
    switch(request.message) {
      case 'setTopic':
        window.selectedTopic = request.data;
      break;
      default:
        sendResponse({data: 'Invalid'})
      break;
    }
  })

  function savetopic(info, tab) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('get', 'http://www.google.com/?q='+selectedTopic)
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(httpRequest.readyState==4) {
      alert(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
  }
}

var contexts = ["selection"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++)
{
    var context = contexts[i];
    chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Send to Google", "contexts":[context], "onclick": savetopic});
}
```

This is the full code of my chrome extension. Did i miss something in the background.js ? I have even that in manifest.json as

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js", "js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

why it is not working? I checked in the background from the inspect views of extension setting and it shows me the following error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: reading the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus) **You must declare the "contextMenus" permission in your app's manifest to use the API** ... have you done so? (hint: you have not :p )

Comment: You need `"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage", "contextMenus"
  ],`

Comment: I gave the permission but the context menu is not displayed and so i get the response undefined.

Comment: Don't forget to reload the extension.

Comment: I have reloaded it.

Comment: I had to use onclick in a different way, something like this ` chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener `.

Answer (score 1):

For your messaging part your problem should be that you are using chrome.extension.onMessage and chrome.extension.sendMessage.

For messaging in chrome you would do this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('req', request.message) // not listened 
    switch(request.message) {
     case 'setTopic':
      window.selectedTopic = request.data;
      break;
     default:
      sendResponse({data: 'Invalid'})
      break;
    }
  });
```

and

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'message': 'setTopic', 'data': topic}, function(response){
  console.log('response', response);
  });
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

Also, for chrome commands api, which you are using, you want to handle commands in the background like this:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
        console.log('Command:', command);
      });
```

instead of doing the hassle of messaging everywhere.

Read about it here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands

Comment: It is still not listened so the selectedTopic is null either.

Comment: You probably also want to add "background" to permissions and also set  persistent : true in the background section

Comment: do you mean like this "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }

?

Comment: yes, because you want the background to always be listning

Comment: Did you test to see if the problem wasn't in the messaging. Maybe it's with how you handle the clicks

Comment: I have here code https://gist.github.com/priyatu/dc62811b726435f6633c9052b903346c in detail. Is this because I am using keyup in content.js and I am trying to send the selected text to server when clicking the text and hitting the send to google option?

Comment: I have consoled the statement inside topic.length condition block and its not consoled that made me believe that the issue is because in that content.js keyup event is used and i am clicking the text to send to the server.

Comment: is this does not execute the function init if right click on the text ? document.addEventListener('click',init);